# Two Icons appearing after name change

Tags: android, icons, google-play

I changed the name of my app by editing the @string/app_name string resource. Now when I download it from the Marketplace, I get two icons on my homescreen - one with the old name and one with the new! I'm stumped. I don't know where the old name is coming from. I did a search on the entire project folder and still can't find it!

And yes, I have just one activity with the action.MAIN and category.LAUNCHER intent filters. So any idea what gives?

Comment: Icon image is sometimes cached by system on some device, reboot your device or adjust the icon order should make system cache refreshed hence remove the cached icon image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested this on another device and only one icon was installed. Must have been something wonky with my development device!

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the package name too when you changed the app_name? If you did then you have two different apks installed on your device and you need to uninstall the old version of the package from the Settings screen.

Comment: When I uninstall one icon from the homescreen, the other one disappears as well. The package name is the same...

Comment: The package name is the same and you have two icons? Then have you labeled two activities with android.intent.category.LAUNCHER in your AndroidManifest.xml There is no other way I know of that this could happen.